# VScode - replace captured group with the values

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code

i have a bunch of strings in code such as:
`<td style="background-color:#fdfdff">&nbsp;</td>`
and
`<td>&nbsp;</td>`
in one file.

The goal is to replace `&nbsp;` from first example with **0**, while `&nbsp;` from second example with **-** (dash)

I'm using VScode regex, but I can't find the way to replace captured groups with specific values, as $1, $2 groups refer to original string groups.
This one is just example, how I'm trying to achieve this, but VScode don't ignore grouped regex.

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_search-and-modify

Comment: Sorry, but what is the rule? And also, since the conditional replacement patterns are not supported, you will have to use *two* regexps,so we need to know what is different between the two patterns. The `style` attribute?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Difference is, that for first one &nbsp; surrounded by td with style attribute, for second without one (just with <td> tag).

Comment: Then use 1) `(?<=<td\s+style="[^"]*">)&nbsp(?=</td>)` and replace with `0`, and 2) `<td>&nbsp;</td>` to replace with `<td>-</td>` (no need for a regex).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. It worked (yes)
The problem was, I've tried to find the way to replace group, but VScode regex working a bit differently

Comment: No, you cannot replace a capturing group in **any** regex. Capturing groups are meant to *keep* captured substrings.

Comment: You can now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 3):

An alternative process is to use a snippet which can do conditional replacements.  With this snippet:

```
    "replaceTDs": {
      "prefix": "tdr",    // whatever prefix you want 
      "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(?<=\">)(&nbsp;)|(&nbsp;)/${1:+0}${2:+-}/g}",
      ]
    }
```

The conditional replacements can be quite simple since you first `find` and select only the two alternative texts you are interested in.  So

find: `<td\s*(style="[^"]*"\s*)>&nbsp;</td>|<td>&nbsp;</td>` old version

This simpler find will probably work for you:

`<td\s*(style="[^"]*")?\s*>&nbsp;</td>`

Don't replace, rather <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  : selects all your two alternatives.  <kbd>Esc</kbd> to focus on editor from the find widget.

Then apply your snippet, in this case type `tdr`+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

and all the changes are made.  You just have to make the snippet one time and then do a single find.

[image: td replacement demo]

---

This technique scales a little better than running as many find/replaces as you have replacements to do.  Even with more conditional replacements it would probably be a simple change to the one snippet to add more replacements.

---

Also you can simplify this even more if you use a keybinding to trigger your snippet (you don't have to change focus from the find widget - or create the separate snippet).  So with no snippet, but this keybinding:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+w",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(?<=\">)(&nbsp;)|(&nbsp;)/${1:+0}${2:+-}/g}"  
    },
    "when": "editorHasSelection"
  }
```

now the same demo:

[image: td replacement keybinding]

Answer (score 2):

You can use

1. Search for `(?<=<td\s+style="[^"]*">)&nbsp;(?=</td>)` and replace with `0`, and
2. Search for `<td>&nbsp;</td>` and replace with `<td>-</td>`, no need for a regex here.

Note that capturing groups are meant to *keep* captured substrings.

The first pattern matches

- `(?<=<td\s+style="[^"]*">)` - a place in string that is immediately preceded with `<td`, one or more whitespaces, `style="`, any zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `>`
- `&nbsp;` - a literal string
- `(?=</td>)` - immediately to the right, there must be `</td>`.